# Error creating JAR file using Command Prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, cmd

I've come across a problem, when trying to package my Java files. I have three Java files: OneMessage.Java, TwoMessage.Java, and AllMessages.Java. I'm on Windows, and so I used cmd to compile these files:

```
javac OneMessage.Java
javac TwoMessage.Java
javac AllMessages.Java
```

I then created a Manifest file - using Notepad - with the following and saved it as Manifest.mf:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Main-Class: AllMessages
```

(There's a single line after "Main-Class: AllMessages".)

However, when I tried to create my executable JAR file, a problem occurs, stating that the system cannot file the file specified (the file is in the source folder btw). And this is what I input to create my JAR file:

```
cvmf AllMessages.jar Manifest.mf *.class
```

However, I get the following: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: Manifest.mf (The system cannot find the file specified".

Help is appreciated as ever.

Answer (score 2):

Not a Java guru, but I think the problem may be that your JAR and Manifest file are ordered wrong. Per the [documentation on the Java options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html), I think that `m` and `f` need to correspond to the ordering of your Manifest and JAR files, respectively. Sounds like it should be:

```
jar cfmv AllMessages.jar Manifest.mf *.class
```

Comment: I tried that, but I got the same problem unfortunately.

Comment: `-cfmv` was working for me, where else `jar -cmf AllMessages.jar Manifest.mf` lead to the totally confusing error message:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: AllMessages.jar (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. I had two sort out two things. My Manifest.mf file was saved as a Text Document, so I went back and changed that to All Files.

I then went onto Oracle and found out that the basic command for creating a JAR file on Command Prompt is:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

So I changed my code from

```
cvmf AllMessages.jar Manifest.mf *.class
```

to

```
cf AllMessages.jar Manifest.mf *.class
```

And I successfully created a JAR file. Note that even if you save your Manifest.mf file as a Text Document, it will still create a JAR file for you.

Link to creating a JAR file: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Comment: For the record, this is not actually a "solution" to your original Manifest issue. The command `jar cf AllMessages.jar Manifest.mf *.class` is creating the default manifest and packaging based on that. You could just as well run `jar cf AllMessages.jar *.class` to acheive the same effect